# Cannot find the setter for attribute android:layout_toRightOf

Tags: android

I am trying to set the following attribute of a view:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@{}"
```

with data binding. I understand that android converts the id for each view in camelCase. when I do

```
<RelativeLayout>

  <TextView  
    android:layout_toRightOf="@{layoutFlag ? myButton : myImageButton }"
  />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"/>

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/my_image_button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error:(79, 45) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_toRightOf' with parameter type android.view.View on android.widget.TextView.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the id o the view, not the actual view.

@{layoutFlag ? "+@id/my_button" : "+@id/my_image_button"}

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the reference to the Objects. Your statement should look more like:

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@{layoutFlag ? yourClass.myButton : yourClass.myImageButton }" />
```

With this in your Layout file:

```
   <data>
       <variable name="yourClass" type="com.example.YourClass"/>
   </data>
```

Please review the Android documentation on `Data Binding`

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

It is hard to really give a detailed answer with the limited code you provided.